# WebService endpoint did not deploy on jboss eap 6

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I have two application servers: one for internal testing (let's call it INT), second one is used for production testing (PRD). INT runs CentOS 6, PRD runs RHEL 6. Both servers also run Jboss EAP 6.2. On this jboss I'm deploying EAR application with a WebService packaged in a war.

**Problem is:** WebService endpoint does not deploy on PRD. No problems on INT. Ear successfully deploys on both servers, endpoint is available on INT, but not on PRD, no errors in server.log both on PRD and INT, PRD server.log suggests, that it has not even tried to deploy the WebService.

**What I have tried:**

1. To eliminate problems with configuration I copied over whole jboss instance (jboss + configuration + deployments + work directories, configuration was adopted - IPs, usernames and password, veirifed with diff) from INT to PRD - no change.
2. Later I also copied over the jre (PRD is running jdk1.7.0_65, INT is running jre1.7.0_67) - also no change.
3. To help me analyse possible issues I created a simple WebService (New Netbeans Web project from wizard, no libraries added, then I added a WebService, also from Wizard) - this project deployed on INT with no issues, WebService was available and working. On PRD it deployed, posted no errors, but the webService was not available - according to the jboss web console it wasn't even started. Checking for wsdl returned 404.

Beacuse of my company's policies I can not post the generated application and server logs.

Answer (score 0):

After further checking i have found the root cause of the problem:

```
11:42:08,396 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: <hostname snipped>
```

Solution:
Adding proper hostname to /etc/hosts file, restart, webServices work